# Clang gives warning about unsupported __declspec attribute

Tags: c++, clang, emscripten

I've been trying to link a third party library to my program. The toolchain is using Clang 4.0.0 to compile (clang is being used in the toolchain by emscripten 1.37.19). I was getting an error about __declspec, and after looking it up, realized I needed to add the -fdeclspec parameter to clang. However, now I get this warning:

```
warning: __declspec attribute 'dllimport' is not supported [-Wignored-attributes]
```

Clang 4.0 docs say this attribute should be supported AFAIK. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is your platform/OS? Does this platforms support dlls?

Comment: Win64. I'm developing an app with Unreal Engine 4.

Comment: Also, using VS 2015.

Comment: What happens if you try `#if __has_declspec_attribute(dllexport)`?

Comment: Extremely late tot he party, but the shared library seems to be doing symbol exporting and assuming a windows environment. If that's the case, you can ask them to write it in a fashion that supports clang and gcc as well. If the use CMake, send them a link to [`GenerateExportHeader`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html).